# How to enable android background location updates?

Tags: android, geolocation, broadcastreceiver

Hey everybody,
I am writing an app that uses geolocation to track a user while he is walking from point A to point B. Here is my code so far:

```
public class LocationTest extends Activity {   
    private static final String[] S = { "out of service", "temporarily unavailable", "available" };
    ArrayList<Location> list = new ArrayList<Location>();
    private TextView output;
    private String best;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationManager mgr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
        best = mgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        log("\nBest provider is: " + best);

        locationListener = new LocationListener(){
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
            dumpLocation(location);
            list.add(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            log("\nProvider status changed: " + provider + ", status=" + S[status]);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            log("\nProvider enabled: " + provider);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            log("\nProvider disabled: " + provider);
        }
    };
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     mgr.requestLocationUpdates(best, 120000, 50, locationListener);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     mgr.removeUpdates(locationListener);
     log_gen(list);
}
```

The app currently displays longitude and latitude whenever new fix is obtained. However, the tracking only works when the Activity is displayed on the screen and as soon as  the user quits the app the tracking stops. What I want my app to do is keep tracking the user in the background even if he quits the app. Whenever he re-opens an app few minutes later, for example, all the coordinates captured in the background should be displayed on the screen.

From what I researched so far, there are two ways one can go about it: either use a background service to do the tracking or use

```
requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, PendingIntent intent)
```

in combination with `BroadcastReceiver` to continue getting location updates even if the user quits the app. If I am understanding correct, the second method would continue running in the background. Can someone please show to me in code how to implement `BroadcastReceiver` with the alternate version of `requestLocationUpdates`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to keep track of location you have to put the tracking system inside a `Service` but you actually don't need a BroadcastReceiver... it's just work fine with the LocationListener

Comment: What approach did you finally use? Were you able to get location updates in the background and use that data, say fire an event based on the location?

Comment: Hi, I need the same requirement. Are you found solution for this.? If so please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code you can get the periodic location updates well if are concerned for the continuously running service you can customise the interval for getting the location updates also you would need to integrate the google play services in you app in order the following code to work

```
public class BackgroundLocationService extends Service implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
// Flag that indicates if a request is underway.
private boolean mInProgress;
private static final String TAG = BackgroundLocationService.class
        .getSimpleName();
private Boolean servicesAvailable = false;

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BackgroundLocationService getServerInstance() {
        return BackgroundLocationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInProgress = false;
    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(Constants.UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(Constants.FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    servicesAvailable = servicesConnected();

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
     * callbacks.
     */
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

}

private boolean servicesConnected() {

    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if (!servicesAvailable || mLocationClient.isConnected() || mInProgress)
        return START_STICKY;

    setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
    if (!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting()
            && !mInProgress) {
        mInProgress = true;
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

/*
 * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
 * callbacks.
 */
private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
    if (mLocationClient == null)
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}

// Define the callback method that receives location updates
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    // Report to the UI that the location was updated
    String msg = Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + ","
            + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("debug", msg);

    if (location != null) {
        // location has the latitude and longitude
    }

    // Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public String getTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    return mDateFormat.format(new Date());
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Turn off the request flag
    mInProgress = false;
    if (servicesAvailable && mLocationClient != null) {
        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        // Destroy the current location client
        mLocationClient = null;
    }
    // Display the connection status
    // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new
    // Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

/*
 * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client
 * finishes successfully. At this point, you can request the current
 * location or start periodic updates
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    // Request location updates using static settings
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);

}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client
 * drops because of an error.
 */
@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // Turn off the request flag
    mInProgress = false;
    // Destroy the current location client
    mLocationClient = null;
    // Display the connection status
    // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new
    // Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

/*
 * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    mInProgress = false;

    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
     * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
     * services activity that can resolve error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

        // If no resolution is available, display an error dialog
    } else {

    }
}
```

[For integrating google play services please refer here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)